# How do I create a Python set with only one element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

If I have a string, and want to create a set that initially contains *only* that string, is there a more Pythonic approach than the following?

```
mySet = set()
mySet.add(myString)
```

The following gives me a set of the letters in `myString`:

```
mySet = set(myString)
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In 2.7 as well as 3.x, you can use:

```
mySet = {'abc'}
```

Comment: In general, the expression `x,` creates a tuple with one element (`x`) - it's a comma that makes a tuple, not parentheses.  `x,` is the same as `(x,)`.

Comment: @TimPeters Yes, but that doesn't apply to sets.

Answer (score 24):

For example, this easy way:

```
mySet = set([myString])
```

Comment: The `set()` builtin expects an iterable type argument. In python, strings can be treated as iterable objects where each character is an element. Attempting to create a `set("my_string")` will instead create a string of its constituent characters. To properly create a set using the builtin function we wrap it in a list here.

Answer (score 7):

[For Python2.7+](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-set_display):

```
set_display ::=  "{" (expression_list | comprehension) "}"
```

**Example:**

```
>>> myString = 'foobar'
>>> s = {myString}
>>> s
set(['foobar'])

>>> s = {'spam'}
>>> s
set(['spam'])
```

Note that an empty **`{}`** is not a `set`, its a `dict`.

Help on `set`:

```
class set(object)
 |  set() -> new empty set object
 |  set(iterable) -> new set object
```

As you can see `set()` expects an iterable and strings are iterable too, so it converts the string characters to a set.

Put the string in some iterable and pass it to `set()`:

```
>>> set(('foo',))  #tuple
set(['foo'])
>>> set(['foo'])   #list
set(['foo'])
```

Answer (score 3):

`set(obj)` is going to iterate trough `obj` and add all unique elements to the set. Since strings are also iterable, if you pass a string to `set()` then you get the unique letters in your set. You can put your obj to a list first:

```
set(["mystring"])
```

However that is not elegant IMO. You know, even for the creation of an empty dictionary we prefer `{}` over `dict()`. Same here. I wolud use the following syntax:

```
myset = {"mystring"}
```

Note that for tuples, you need a comma after it:

```
mytuple = ("mystring",)
```

Answer (score 1):

**use `mySet = {mystring}`**

```
 Python 3.6.9 (default, Sep 24 2019, 14:35:19)                                                                                             
 Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information                                                                             
 IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.                                                                       

 In [1]: def s(i):                                                                                                                         
     ...:     r = set()                                                                                                                     
     ...:     r.add(i)                                                                                                                      
     ...:     return r                                                                                                                      
     ...:                                                                                                                                   

 In [2]: %timeit s(1234)                                                                                                                   
  218 ns ± 5.99 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)                                                                

 In [3]: %timeit set([1234])                                                                                                               
  201 ns ± 3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)                                                                  

 In [4]: %timeit {1234}                                                                                                                    
  51.7 ns ± 1.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the set also isn't likely to change, consider using a `frozenset`:

```
mySet = frozenset([myString])
```